# DecimalFormat rounding

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal

Here is small code to illustrate what I am seeing

```
float floater = 59.999f;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.0");

System.out.println(df.format(floater));
```

This prints:

```
60.0
```

I would like it to print

```
59.9
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add this line before using the `DecimalFormat`:

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Take a look at the other rounding modes and see which one is best for you.

Note : this method works only in JDK 1.6 or above

Comment: [DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode))

Answer (score 3):

```
float d = 59.999f;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
// Use the returned value from setScale, as it doesn't modify the caller.
bd = bd.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
String formatted = bd.toString();
```

Comment: Generally it is bad decision cause it changes data, whereas all we need to change view

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I'd much rather say that this is awful slow. And requires creating a BigDecimal. But as for how it "changes data" - I don't see... The original float is untouched, ready for use by anything. Would you elaborate more on your comment?

Comment: @ppeterka fair point. It's been a little less than year ago, likely I was thinking from *how do I round my bigdecimal* point of view, can't say now

Comment: upvoted, nothing wrong with this answer, especially for java 1.5 or lower.  Also as pointed out above it doesn't change the data even if you are already starting with a BigDecimal; BigDecimal.setScale returns a new instance of BigDecimal and doesn't alter the original. "Note that since BigDecimal objects are immutable, calls of this method do not result in the original object being modified"