# How do I round a double that I've converted into a string in java?

Tags: java, string, rounding

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work? I'm confident it's because i'm trying to format a string to two decimal places.. but i don't know how else to make the output rounded to decimal places.

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    String sTotalCost = Double.toString(totalCost);

    txtTotalCost.setText("£" + df.format(sTotalCost));
```

Comment: Just don't convert to a string beforehand...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 10 seconds late... :)

Comment: protip: don't use floating point values for monetary systems.  You want to be working with either the total actual fractional currency as an integer, or two values for the unit and fractional portion.

Comment: To expand on caskey's comment, use `java.math.BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: What about accepting an answer? Or are the not solving your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Don't convert it to a string before formatting:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
txtTotalCost.setText("£" + df.format(totalCost));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just like to **round for displaying purpose (as String)**, you did it correct. Just set the Roundmode that fits for you:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

txtTotalCost.setText("£" + df.format(totalCost));
```

See: [DecimalFormat rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447153/decimalformat-rounding)

---

If you like to **calculate on the rounded variable**, you should round it like this:

```
double roundedTotalCost = Math.round(totalCost*100.0)/100.0
```

See: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-round-double-float-value-to-2-decimal-points-in-java/