# Multiply with two Decimal Place - Java

Tags: java

multiply the double Type number, from the output need to taken with two Decimal Place

```
double creditCardPercentage = 0.03;
String renewalEventAmount = "2144.60";
double expectedRenewalAmount = 0;
expectedRenewalAmount = Double.parseDouble(renewalEventAmount) * creditCardPercentage;
```

the output for the expectedRenewalAmount is `64.338`, then how can we format the above output with two decimal

Expected:

```
64.33
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447153/decimalformat-rounding

Comment: @Prabu Are you only concerned with the formatting of the output, or, going with the example you gave, would you be doing further maths with the output?

Comment: When dealing with currency its generally not a great idea to use double arithmetic since it isn't precise. It is better to convert them to ints (by multiplying by some multiple of 10 and then divide by a multiple of ten depending on how many decimal places you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(expectedRenewalAmount)` which will use the system properties to format the value.  You can also modify the `NumberFormat`, specifying the number of decimal places if you want.

Or you could use `System.out.printf` or `String.format` to format the value as well...

```
String value = String.format("%.2f", expectedRenewalAmount);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `BigDecimal` class because it has built-in handling for floating point precision:

```
BigDecimal creditCardPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.03);
String renewalEventAmountString = "2144.60";
BigDecimal renewalEventAmount = new BigDecimal(renewalEventAmountString);
BigDecimal expectedRenewalAmount = renewalEventAmount.multiply(creditCardPercentage);
expectedRenewalAmount = expectedRenewalAmount.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

System.out.println(expectedRenewalAmount); // prints 64.33
```

One of the advantages of using `BigDecimal` to handle the formatting is that it allows you to separate your code from your business logic, i.e. rounding down to 2 decimal places, from the view code which outputs the result to the user.

Answer (score 2):

A couple answers have suggested `printf`; but if you don't want to print the answer right away, you can use `String.format` the same way:

```
String formattedString = String.format("%.2f", expectedRenewalAmount);
```

and now you can print out the result if you want, or you can display it in a Swing text window or change all the zeros to happy faces or do whatever else you like with the resulting string, which you can't do with `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `printf()` function with `%f`:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", expectedRenewalAmount);
```

Here you can find a beautiful [printf format cheat sheet](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) by Alvin Alexander that might help you (and hopefully others) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this while printing:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", expectedRenewalAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double creditCardPercentage = 0.03;
String renewalEventAmount = "2144.60";
double expectedRenewalAmount = 0;
expectedRenewalAmount = df.format(Double.parseDouble(renewalEventAmount) * creditCardPercentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `minimumFractionDigit` to 0

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(format(14.0184849945)); // prints '14.01'
        System.out.println(format(13)); // prints '13'
        System.out.println(format(3.5)); // prints '3.5'
        System.out.println(format(3.138136)); // prints '3.13'
    }

    public static String format(Number n) {
        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return format.format(n);
    }

}
```

please find below reference link.

[Java: Use DecimalFormat to format doubles and integers but keep integers without a decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309189/java-use-decimalformat-to-format-doubles-and-integers-but-keep-integers-without)