# Rounding off double to closest (minimum) value

Tags: java, double, rounding, decimalformat

I have a method which sometimes returns 0.28 / 0.23 .
I am using the below class

`DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.#");`

but here I need this code to return me 0.2 every-time , but when its more than 0.25 its returns 0.3 by rounding it off to closet decimal .

But i want my code to return 0.2 every-time the value varies from 0.21 to 0.29.
can someone help me with this ?

Comment: `System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.29999).setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DecimalFormat rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447153/decimalformat-rounding)

Comment: @Jorn  Your format is incorrect and throws throws an exception. I presume you meant `"%.1f"`.  But `String.format` rounds half up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

Casting a floating-point value to an integer will truncate the decimal.
So, you could utilize this by first multiplying by 10, truncating the value, and then re-dividing by 10.

```java
float valueA = 0.28f;
float valueB = 0.23f;
valueA = ((int) (valueA * 10)) / 10f;
valueB = ((int) (valueB * 10)) / 10f;
```

Output

```
valueA = 0.2
valueB = 0.2
```

Additionally, you can utilize the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class.
The *[setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int))* method allows you to set the amount of digits after the decimal point, in addition to setting a *[RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html)*.

There are numerous types of *rounding modes*, see the *RoundingMode* JavaDoc linked above, for a table of values.

I believe you are looking for *[FLOOR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR)*, or *[DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN)*, for the truncation.

Here is an example using *DOWN*.

```java
BigDecimal valueA = new BigDecimal("0.28");
BigDecimal valueB = new BigDecimal("0.23");
valueA = valueA.setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN);
valueB = valueB.setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Output

```
valueA = 0.2
valueB = 0.2
```

On a final note, you could just parse the value as a *String* and substring the value for 1 digit after the decimal point.

```java
float valueA = 0.28f;
float valueB = 0.23f;
String stringA = String.valueOf(valueA);
valueA = Float.parseFloat(stringA.substring(0, stringA.indexOf('.') + 2));
String stringB = String.valueOf(valueB);
valueB = Float.parseFloat(stringB.substring(0, stringB.indexOf('.') + 2));
```

Output

```
valueA = 0.2
valueB = 0.2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html) to round down.

```java
df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as follows without using `DecimalFormat`.  To round down to the nearest `10th`, just multiple by `10`, casting as an `int` and then divide by `10d`.

```
double[] data = {
        .21,.22,.22,.23,.24,.25,.26,.27,.28,.29
};
for (double value : data) {
    System.out.println(value + "  ->  " + ((int) (value * 10)) / 10d);
}
```

prints

```
0.21  ->  0.2
0.22  ->  0.2
0.22  ->  0.2
0.23  ->  0.2
0.24  ->  0.2
0.25  ->  0.2
0.26  ->  0.2
0.27  ->  0.2
0.28  ->  0.2
0.29  ->  0.2
```